# How to set a portfolio turnover ratio threshold according to volatility?

Tags: portfolio-management, risk-management

With the various crises affecting the financial markets, here a pandemic, this ratio skyrockets almost every time, which limits its interpretability.

We know that the [ratio increased during the subprime financial crisis](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Efinance/020601/news/Schultz%20Paper%20-%202006.pdf), for example, and that it continuously decreased thereafter, until we were affected by Covid-19, Brexit and US elections. So with all this things happening it should be quite normal that managers would make up their mind and just shift in the strategy of the funds.

I'm aware of modified turnover rate, churn rate and Cremers and Pareek duration measure, but I don't think they solve it.

So is that a solution would be to adjust the ratio to the volatility (index or whatsoever) ? Or would it lose its purpose ([because after all a study prove that it's most relevant in times of stress](http://www.aabri.com/manuscripts/203187.pdf)) ? I thought about using a benchmark and beta.

[Qian, Hua and H. Sorensen (2007)](https://jpm.pm-research.com/content/34/1/27) gave a bit of a hint with the following formula :

$TO = \sqrt{\frac{N}{\pi}}\sigma_p \sqrt{1-\rho_z(1)} E_{cs}(\frac{1}{\sigma_i})$,

where :
$N$ number of stocks in selection universe,
$\sigma_p $ : portfolio’s target tracking error,
$\sigma_i$ : stock i’s specific risk,
$\rho_z(1)$: first order alpha signal correlation.

It's obviously not really appropriate for setting a threshold but there is an idea, I don't really know how to adapt it, someone could help please ?

Thanks !

Comment: which formula for portfolio turnover

Comment: Sorry, the one from CSSF, so $Turnover = ((Total 1 – Total 2)/M)*100$ with  Total 1 = Sum of all security transactions (purchases and sales) made during the period; Total
2 = Sum of all creations and redemptions made during the period; M = Average Net Assets of the fund.

Comment: CSSF = Commission de Surveillance du Secteur Financier ? https://www.cssf.lu/en/about-the-cssf/

Comment: Yes, Indeed. They don't give anything to work with thresholds so I was wondering myself about that.